# How to find execution time (if possible in nanoseconds) of the sections in a C code on linux with intel dual core?

Tags: c

I have a C code with some functions.I need to find out the execution time of each function, I have tried using gettimeofday and rdtsc,but i guess that because its multi core system the output time provided involves the switching time between the processors. I wanted it to be serialized. So if somebody can give me an idea that how should i calulate the time or at least let me know about the syntax of rdstcp.

P.S. please reply as soon as possible
Thanks :)

Comment: run it on single core computer and check the time

Comment: >  please reply as soon as possible -- are you timing us?

Comment: -1 for the stupid last sentence.

Answer (score 3):

It's a little impractical to expect nanosecond resolution.

You can't add code *just to output the execution times of functions* without increasing execution time. When you take the code out, the timing changes.

In practice, this kind of measurement is made by observing the CPU timing signals on an oscilloscope (or logic analyser).

Comment: why is it not possible using clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&start) & timespec structure ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple cores, then the CPU timer won't be stable between them. So set the [thread affinity](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setaffinity) to keep it on the one core. You also might want to use a [real time timer](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime) to measure the time for the process or thread using `clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIMER_ID)`. Read the note for SMP systems in the usage for that function.

Both of these will effect the timing of the program, so perform multiple iterations of whatever you are benchmarking, and don't call the timing functions too often to try and mitigate this.

Answer (score 1):

There should be some way to set processor affinity to tell the operating system to only run that thread on a particuar core.

In windows there is a SetThreadAffinity system call, I imagine there is a similar function in linux, although I don't know what it is called.

Answer (score 1):

You could boot your dual core system to use one core only using the following kernel parameter:

```
maxcpus=1
```

But the measured time will still comprise process contest switching and thus depend on the activity on the other processes on the system. Are you interested in the execution time, or the CPU time needed to execute your task ?

Answer (score 0):

Mate, I'm not sure about this, but even if you're dual core,unless the program is threaded, it will only run in 1 thread (meaning 1 core), so it should not involve the time of switching between processors, I believe there is no such thing...

Comment: It's entirely possible for processes to start on one core and then next time they are scheduled to run their next time slice on a different code.

Answer (score 0):

Pavium is correct, the only way to get decent timing at this resolution in with an oscilloscope and toggling GPIO pins.
Bear in mind that this is all a bit academic anyway: I suppose you are running with an operating system, etc, so there is no way to get a straight run at the hardware.

You really need to look at the reason you want this measurement.  Is it a performance benchmark for some code?  You could try running the code many thousands of times and get some statistics.  For this kind of approach I would recommend you read [Zed Shaws diatribe](http://www.zedshaw.com/essays/programmer_stats.html) to make sure the numbers aren't fooling you.

Answer (score 0):

Precise Performance Measuring was impossible until Linux kernel 2.6.31. In this kernel a new library for accessing the performacne counters of the CPU and IMHO correcting times in the scheduler was added.

Unfortunately i don't have more details but maybe it is a starting point for more information search. I'm just adding this because nobody mentioned it before

Answer (score 0):

Use the `struct timespec` structure & `clock_gettime` function as follows to obtain the time of execution of the code in nanoseconds precision

```
struct timespec start, end;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&start);
/* Do something */
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&end);
```

It returns a value as `((((unsigned64)start.tv_sec) * ((unsigned64)(1000000000L))) + ((unsigned64)(start.tv_nsec))))`

Moreover this I've used for multithreaded concepts too..

Hope this answer will be more helpful for you to get your desired execution time in nanoseconds.